# Hyperlink is not working with angular-fullstack yo generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, href, mean-stack

I am working with the angular-fullstack yo generator (https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack). It's a simple app just to try out the generator, but I have a problem when I am trying to make a simple hyperlink.

When I use the attribute (href='somewebsite.com') the link goes to "localhost:9000/somewebsite.com" instead of just "somewebsite.com". I think it's because something in the routes in the express server but I'm not sure.
Can someone help me with this noob question...? :P

Thanks.
E.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a relatively old question now but the issue is that you are missing the `http://` from the front of your `href`. It's not an angular or express issue just a regular html issue.

Hope that helps! :-)

Comment: What a noob question right :P Thank you for your help :)

Comment: We all had to start somewhere! :-)